# Delete the first element of each sublist

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am supposed to write a function which will delete the first element of each sublist.

So if we are given  (1 (2 (3 4) 5) 6), my function should return (((4)5)6)

```
(defun izbrisiPrv(lista)
    (cdr lista)
)


(defun podlista(l)
    (cond
        ((null l) nil)
        ((atom (car l)) (podlista(cdr l)))
        ((listp (car l)) (cons (izbrisiPrv(car l)) (cdr l)))
        (t (cons (podlista(car l)) (podlista(cdr l))))
    )
)


(print (podlista '(1 (2 (3 4) 5) 6)))
```

This is what I have tried but it returns
(((3 4) 5) 6)

(the 3 should not be there)

Any ideas?

Comment: It would be nice if you used standard indentation and paren placing. English  function names wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Note that there are simpler cases for which your code doesn't work correctly, such as `'(1 2)`, which returns `NIL` instead of the expected `(2)`.

Answer (score 1):

## Your code

Your `podlista` function has 4 [`cond`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_cond.htm) clauses, and the last one is unreachable. This is because every Lisp object is either an [`atom`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_atom.htm) or a [`cons`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_cons.htm), and [`listp`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_listp.htm) will return `t` for a `cons`.

The next problem is the third clause is non-recursive (you have to drop first elements in the `cdr`).

However, there is a bigger problem with your code.
When the function sees a `cons`, it has to know whether the first element is to be dropped or not. IOW, it must either

- have a loop (or a map) to process lists non-recursively, or
- take a second argument to specify first/non-first position in the list

## Solution 1  - loop/map

Assuming you are permitted to
use [`mapcar`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mapc_.htm), the solution is

```
(defun drop-first (l)
  (if (consp l)
      (mapcar #'drop-first (rest l))
      l))
(drop-first '(1 ((7 8) 9) (2 (3 4) 5) 6))
==> ((9) ((4) 5) 6)
(drop-first '(1 (2 (3 4) 5) 6))
==> (((4) 5) 6)
```

`mapcar` is, of course, defined recursively as

```
(defun mapcar (f l) 
  (and l 
       (cons (funcall f (first l))
             (mapcar f (rest l)))))
```

## Solution 2 - extra argument

```
(defun first-drop (l &optional (top-level t)) 
  (cond ((atom l) l)
        (t
         (when top-level        ; drop first list element
           (pop l))
         ;; collect all the list element
         (cons (first-drop (car l) t) ; drop first in the CAR
               (first-drop (cdr l) nil))))) ; do NOT drop first in the rest of the list
```

## Test

```
(defparameter *test-cases*      ; list of (ARG RET)
  '(((1 2 3) (2 3))
    ((1 (2 (3 4) 5) 6) (((4) 5) 6))
    ((1 (3 (5 6) 4) (7 8 9) 2) (((6) 4) (8 9) 2))))
(loop :for (arg ret) :in *test-cases* :do
  (assert (equal (drop-first arg) ret))
  (assert (equal (first-drop arg) ret)))
```

Comment: I'm rather looking to understand what's wrong with my code, I've never used mapcar and I've no idea what it does.